# Save emails daily incorporating if filename are duplicates

Tags: vba, outlook

I am writing a macro that will save emails daily. I just thought of a situation that can possibly occur. I sometimes receive emails with the same subject from the sender, but each email has different content. I would like to have a set of statements that will handle this. Maybe have it say that it is a copy, or maybe even append the time as well to the file name. This is the code that I have right now.

```
Public Sub SaveMsgs(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
 Dim sPath As String
 Dim dtDate As Date
 Dim sName As String
 Dim enviro As String
 Dim sSender As String
 Dim strFolder As String
 Dim strNewFolder As String
 Dim save_to_folder As String
 Dim strMyPath as String
 Dim intCount as Integer
 Dim 

 enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))

 sName = Item.Subject
 ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, "_"

 sSender = Item.Sender

 dtDate = Item.ReceivedTime
 sName = sSender & " - " & sName & ".msg"

 strNewFolder = Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy")
 strFolder = "C:\IT Documents\" & strNewFolder & "\"

 If Len(Dir(strFolder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
   MkDir (strFolder)
 End If

 save_to_folder = strFolder

 Item.SaveAs save_to_folder & sName, olMSG
End Sub

Private Sub ReplaceCharsForFileName(sName As String, _
     sChr As String _)

 sName = Replace(sName, "/", sChr)
 sName = Replace(sName, "\", sChr)
 sName = Replace(sName, ":", sChr)
 sName = Replace(sName, "?", sChr)
 sName = Replace(sName, Chr(34), sChr)
 sName = Replace(sName, "<", sChr)
 sName = Replace(sName, ">", sChr)
 sName = Replace(sName, "|", sChr)
End Sub
```

Here is the code that I was thinking bout adding.

```
Do While True 
  strMyPath = strFolder & sName 
  If objFSO>FileExists(strMyPath) Then 
    intCount = intCount + 1 
    sName = Copy (" & intCount & ") 
  Else Exit Do 
  End If 
Loop
```

Would something like this work for what I am trying to do, or would it be better to append the time to the filename?

Comment: At first please remove that `Dim` at end of your declarations ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save with Date Time Seconds & Subject you could do

```
 sName = Format(dtDate, "MM-DD-YYYY", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
                    vbUseSystem) & Format(dtDate, "-hhnnss", _
                    vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & "-" & sName & ".msg"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. That seems to have done the trick. Now I am working on so that way it doesn't show up all as one string without any separation marks. But I can play around with that. But another issue I am having that I just noticed, for some reason a response email comes back with the file type of "file" rather than ".msg" For example, I received a email from Joe, I respond, and then Joe responds back, that response comes through as a "file" file type. Any ideas why this is? I have re-read the code and I can't seem to figure this out right now.